# how to run Selenium tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I want to run my Selenium Webdriver Maven tests in Jenkins. I've followed the tutorial: https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html  and   https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s06.html
But now, I want to run each of hundreds tests that I've written in Selenium Webdriver with Eclipse.

I use Maven to create testng.xml (where I have my Maven projects to can execute a list of tests in the same execution). 
I use Eclipse to write Java to create tests in Selenium Webdriver.
I use github to import tests.

I show you my github project... I don't know how to access into the different folders to execute each testng.xml files, sorry, I'm pretty new here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: If I am reading your question right, you have written TestNG test cases using WebDriver and have kept them in a GitHub repository and now you want to pull those test cases and execute them using Jenkins?

Comment: That's right!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a freestyle Jenkins job and then go to the configuration page of your job and in `Source Code Management` section add the URL of your Git repo where you have kept your TestNG tests. This will help to bring the tests from the repository to your workspace.
2. Then go to the `Build` section and select `Execute windows batch script` if and then add the following script:

   `java -cp ".;/path/to/testng-x.x.x.jar;/path/to/jcommander-x.xx.jar;/path/to/test-classes" org.testng.TestNG /path/to/test.xml`

   For `Linux` use the following script with `Execute shell` in `Build step:

   `cd /path/to/test.xml
   java -cp "/path/to/testng-x.x.x.jar:/path/to/bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

   Where `/bin` folder contains the compiled code for the TestNG tests.
3. Then save the job and run the build to execute TestNG test cases.

Note: You can find the required JAR files inside the `.m2` folder.

Comment: Hi @Anil , thanks so much for your fast response. I have doubts... when you put: "x.x.x"...I don't know what I should write because I don't have any "version" of my testng (each file testng is called the same way in all hundred tests)...

Comment: And another question... does that script give me the opportunity to navigate through all my test folders?... thanks a lot!

Comment: I show you my output console after executing your Linux Script: in other answer...

Comment: Please add your console output to the comment section of my answer. That's not an answer.

Comment: I just ignored that "x.x.x" and I wrote "1.5.0.jar" and I got the same output console.

Comment: The issue here is you are using `path/to/test.xml`, this is just an example path. You have to replace it with the path wherever you have your `testng.xml` file. Also, do the same with the other example paths I have mentioned.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, I'm back from my holidays and I'm still asleep... sorry! I'll change it right now!! ;P

Comment: I wrote the correct path for the files but I got the same failure...: 

+ cd /cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/testng.xml
/tmp/hudson735039243505472339.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /cua/Researches/Filtro
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You can't use the file name with path with `cd` command. 
Just do `cd "/cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/"`

Comment: I wrote this code in Configuration Project: (I've deleted "testng.xml" in the first line as you said to me):

cd "/cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/"
java -cp "/cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades-1.5.0.jar:/cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/src/test/java/paquete/
" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: And I get the following Output Console:

+ cd /cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/
/tmp/hudson2620945203684152183.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /cua/Researches/Filtro Afinidad Entidades - Anual y Trimestral - Ppales Entidades/
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I don't know exactly if my version of  .jar is 1.5.0. I have a lot of .jar files in .m2 folder . I've chosen the version of this file: java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar  but I don't know if that's correct... (sorry, I know I'm very lost, thanks so much for your patience).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152027/discussion-between-anil-mahapatra-official-and-usermb).